# Simulate 'click' in Angular unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following link function in my Angular directive definition object:

```
function link(scope, element) {
  var blurred = angular.element(element[0].getElementsByClassName('blur'));
  blurred.on('click', function() {
    blurred.css({'-webkit-filter': 'none'});
  });
}
```

I'm attempting to test that `'-webkit-filter': 'none'` is added as a style upon clicking the 'blurred' element with the below test. My problem is that both console.log's are the same; the style I would expect to have been added never is.

```
it('should add the necessary style when clicked', function() {
  var blurred = angular.element(element[0].getElementsByClassName('blur'));
  console.log(blurred);
  blurred.triggerHandler('click');
  console.log(blurred);
});
```

The logged value looks like this in both cases:

```
{0: <div class="blur ng-binding">

    <br>

    <br>
  </div>, length: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add wait after click to avoid race condition if any

```
`waits(500);` //  avoid race condition
```